# mysql use concat on sum() function like concat(sum(col1),"%")

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, union, type-coercion

i am trying to union multiple queries but one of the query uses sum() when i try to apply concat on this column i get undesired (blob ? ) result  how can i apply concat and union on aggregated column.
i was expecting this  result

```
SELECT "row 1" col1 UNION  SELECT concat((5),"%");
```

returns

```
# col1
'row 1'
'5%'
```

but

```
SELECT "row 1" col1 UNION  SELECT concat(sum(5),"%");
```

returns 'blob' result below

```
# col1
?
?
```

how can i apply the concat()in summd column result .

Comment: `SUM()` is for summing an expression across multiple rows in the table. It makes no sense if you're not selecting from a table.

Comment: It works fine in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e1dea7ba1fae13fb50f16c3d3231daf.

Comment: I tested your code in 2 Mysql fiddles and you are right about the unexpected result. I don't know why this happens. As a workaround use: `SELECT "row 1" col1 UNION  SELECT concat(sum(5) + 0, "%");` which works as expected. Check here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6DWP7SDT5YJufi7sedaTQ9/0 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/193833

Comment: @forpas answer it and let me accept

Comment: @Seyid it's fine. In fact this is not a solution, it's only a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case for `CONCAT`, because you have included the `SUM(5)` expression in its raw form which will *always* return a numeric value, the `CONCAT` result will be a binary string. To fix this, simply `CAST` the numeric expression elements to `CHAR` first: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/319356

```
SELECT "row 1" col1 UNION  SELECT concat(CAST(sum(5) as CHAR),"%");
```

You can also rely on implicit conversion instead of `CONCAT` for the same result:

```
SELECT "row 1" col1 UNION  SELECT sum(5) + "%";
```

| col1 |
| --- |
| row 1 |
| 5% |

> **[MySQL: CONCAT Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/concat.php)**
>
> - If expression is a numeric value, it will be converted by the CONCAT function to a binary string.
> - If all expressions are nonbinary strings, the CONCAT function will return a nonbinary string.
> - If any of the expressions is a binary string, the CONCAT function will return a binary string.
> - If any of the expressions is a NULL, the CONCAT function will return a NULL value.

You can prove this with a very simple query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/319354

```
SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(*))
```

Results in:

```
MQ==
```

But then if you `CAST` it to `CHAR` the response is readable: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/319355

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR))
```

Results:

```
1
```

---

Now what really [bakes your noodle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/18935) is *Why did it work in the first query?*

In MySQL (and many other databases) most cases a numeric-type constant/literal is automatically coerced to the most appropriate type depending on context. When necessary, you can force a numeric value to be interpreted as a specific data type by casting it explicitly.

The reverse is also true, a string *literal* that represents a number will often be coerced into the appropriate numeric type.

- The most common scenario where we tend to *abuse* coercion is when using `Date` or `DateTime` literals in expressions, the string literal notation is the simplest way to get the value in.

This is a feature of the engine that *parses* your query, not of the execution. So if you use a parameterized query or you are referencing column values, this *coercion* does not occur. For the cast of `concat((5),"%")` the 5 is *coerced* to a string `'5'`. For `sum(5)` the 5 is interpreted as an integer.

> **[12.3 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)**
> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts strings to numbers as necessary, and vice versa.

Finally, in regard to `UNION`, MySQL will attempt to convert the results of associated columns to the type that can natively represent the values from all of the queries:

> **[13.2.9.3 UNION Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)**
> If the data types of corresponding SELECT columns do not match, the types and lengths of the columns in the UNION result take into account the values retrieved by all the SELECT statements.

---

A final special case in response to a comment by @forpas

> As a workaround use: `SELECT "row 1" col1 UNION  SELECT concat(sum(5) + 0, "%");`

The reason that `sum(5) + 0` *works* is probably better described by using `CONCAT(CAST(SUM(5) as SIGNED)+CAST(SUM(0) as SIGNED), "%")` which is *almost* specific. MySQL evaluates each sub-expression individually, but Similar to `UNION` it considers all the type information of the inputs and outputs at the specific context of the expression. So in this case it is the `+` operator that *tricks* the engine into re-checking *all* the type information in the current *context* to determine the most appropriate type.

This behaviour is a reason why you might choose to use, or avoid `CONCAT` for non-strings in the first place in MySQL and just used this expression: `SELECT sum(5) + "%";`

```
SELECT concat(5,"%")
, concat(SUM(5), "%")
, concat(SUM(5)+0, "%")
,5+"%"
,concat(SUM(5)+SUM(0), "%")
,CONCAT(CAST(SUM(5) as SIGNED)+CAST(SUM(0) as SIGNED), "%")
;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/319381

| concat(5,"%") | concat(SUM(5), "%") | concat(SUM(5)+0, "%") | 5+"%" | concat(SUM(5)+SUM(0), "%") | CONCAT(CAST(SUM(5) as SIGNED)+CAST(SUM(0) as SIGNED), "%") |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5% | NSU= | 5% | 5 | 5% | 5% |